# Xamarin Android ¿Cómo crear un bitmap utilizando un Uri?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Estoy creando un Intent para abrir la galería de imagenes del telefono y una vez que se selecciona una imagen guardo el Uri de esa imagen en una string que se ubica en las SharedPreferences, después en otra actividad leo la cadena Uri e intento crear un Bitmap usando BitmapFactory.DecodeFile pero retorna null, mi suposición es que estoy mandando mal el path del archivo pero entonces como se lo mando o que debería mandar como parametro?

Codigo para abrir la galería de imagenes:

```
private void SelectImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Selecciona una imagen"), 0);
}
```

Callback para cuando se selecciona una imagen en la gallería:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var uriStr = data.Data.ToString();
                var userPreferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserPreferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
                var prefs = userPreferences.Edit();
                prefs.PutString("ProfileImage", uriStr);
                prefs.Commit();

                var imageView = FindViewById<CircleImageView>(Resource.Id.circleimage);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data); //Aquí la imagen si se muestra en el CircleImageView
            }
        }
```

y donde estoy intentado crear el Bitmap:

```
        var userPreferences = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserPreferences", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var imageUri = userPreferences.GetString("ProfileImage", "");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imageUri); //Retorna null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap imageBitmap;
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData("/*URL de la imagen */ img");
    if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
    {
        imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        ImageView.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```